# Angular2 - trouble reading data from my HTTP GET

Tags: angular, web-applications

I am developing an Angular2 application.  I have a service file called `submit.service.ts` that defines my GET request:

```
GET(URL: string): Promise<any> {
  return this.http.get(URL)
    .toPromise()
    .then(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body.data || { };
}
```

Then, in my main component class, I have the method where I call the GET request:

```
constructor(private sService:submitService, private EngageVar:EngageVariables) { }

ngOnInit() { 
}

//EngageVar is a class of variables I created to store all my variables
returnDetails() {

            this.EngageVar.listOfIDs = this.sService.GET('myURL' + this.EngageVar.IDSearch);               
            this.EngageVar.hideTable = false;
            var keys = Object.keys(this.EngageVar.listOfIDs);
            var len = keys.length;
            this.EngageVar.lengthOfRecords = len;

        }
```

When I make the call, I can see in the network debugger that I am getting a valid response like:

```
[{id:1,name:John},{id:2,name:Jane}]
```

However, in my application, when I am trying to use the data from the GET call, it just has `[Object object]` or `["__zone_symbol__state", "__zone_symbol__value"]`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS(V1) and Angular(V2+) are different in term of Http
I can see that you are trying to get `response.data`after changing response to JSON by `res.json();`

second, you are converting your HTTP call from Observable to Promise which is not a good Idea in this example(please read about RxJS)

the following example will work

Service:

```
GET(URL: string): Promise<any> {
  return this.http.get(URL)
    .map( (res: Response) => rs.json() );
}
```

Controller:

```
returnDetails() {
    this.sService.GET('myURL' + this.EngageVar.IDSearch)
        .subscribe( data => {
            let keys = Object.keys(data);
            this.EngageVar.hideTable = false;
            this.EngageVar.listOfIDs = data;
            this.EngageVar.lengthOfRecords: keys.length;
        });
}
```